# How to quicksort user input

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

The question is rather simple but the more I search the more confused I get. I'm supposed to quicksort a variable from the struct code I've written. However, I don't understand how I'm supposed to quicksort a variable like em.fName if it's changed every iteration of the loop. Every example I look up seems to sort int variables or predefined character arrays. Could some one point me in the right direction where to start and/or give an example in C? Thanks, greatly appreciate it. I've [posted the full code here](http://pastebin.com/Pb4iFqZt) since I didn't want to clutter the post.

```
    typedef struct EmployeeRecord
    {
    STR21 lName;
    STR11 fName;
    char fullName[33];
    float hrs;
    float pay;
    float dfr;
    float gross;
    float ft;
    float st;
    float ssit;
    float net;

    } EmployeeRecord;

int main(void)
{
    EmployeeRecord em;

    do
    {
        counter++;
        em.dfr = em.ft = em.st = em.ssit = em.gross = em.hrs = em.pay = em.net = ovrtHrs = 0; //initalized to 0 and then changed by function if greater than 0
        printf("Please enter your FIRST name: ");
        scanf("%s",fName);
        printf("Please enter your LAST name: ");
        scanf("%s",lName);
        printf("Enter your payrate: ");
        scanf("%f",&em.pay);
        printf("Please enter your total hours: ");
        scanf("%f",&em.hrs);
        printf("Please enter the amount of deferred earnings: ");
        scanf("%f",&em.dfr);

        strcpy(fullName,lName); // combine last + ", " + first into full
                strcat(fullName,", ");
                strcat(fullName,fName);

        payTotal = payTotal + em.pay;
        dfrTotal = dfrTotal + em.dfr;

        em.gross = grossModule(&em.hrs,em.pay,&ovrtHrs); // call 3.4
        CalculateTaxes(&em.gross,&em.dfr,&em.ft,&em.st,&em.ssit); // call 3.0
        em.net = netModule(&em.gross,&em.ft,&em.st,&em.ssit); // cal 3.5

        hoursTotal = hoursTotal + em.hrs;
        overtimeTotal = overtimeTotal + ovrtHrs; // TOTALS
        grossTotal = grossTotal + em.gross;
        stateTotal = stateTotal + em.st;
        ssiTotal = ssiTotal + em.ssit;
        netTotal = netTotal + em.net;
        fedTotal = fedTotal + em.ft;

        fprintf(myreport,REPORTCOLUMNFORMATS,em.fullName,em.pay,em.hrs,em.gross,em.ft,em.ssit,em.net);
        fprintf(myreport,REPORTCOLUMNFORMATS3,ovrtHrs,em.st,em.dfr);


        printf("Would you like to continue, y/n? \n");
        scanf("%s",&ask);

    }while(ask == 'y' || ask == 'Y');
```

Comment: `every irritation of the loop` lol.

Comment: Sort and ... put where?

Comment: @Jashaszun woops, meant iteration, my bad lol.

Comment: Prepare an array that can save all the records.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well it just says "Write a C function capable of implementing a quicksort upon an array of employee records." I could just print them out in a separate file or the console.

Comment: If `ask` is a `char` you need to use `scanf("%c",&ask);` instead of `scanf("%s",&ask)`, and if `ask` is an array of chars you can not compare using `while(ask == 'y' || ask == 'Y');`

Comment: @Dan So... don't you think you need some kind of  a storage?

Comment: @EugeneSh. just edited my comment.

Comment: BTW, since you are receiving the data one by one the more appropriate sorting in my opinion would be "insertion sort". Or a "binary insertion sort", which would improve the complexity for a picky reviewer.

Comment: @AlterMann I used scanf("%s",&ask) because it was picking up the space from the \n. I could use scanf(" %c",&ask) with the space before %c but since %s is working fine I left it like that so I don't have to worry about the space. It helps prevent headaches in the future if I were to accidentally remove the space from scanf(" %c",&ask).

Comment: @Dan, ok, but using `%s` for a `char` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would have gladly used a binary insertion sort especially since the professor explained it in class and gave code samples of implementation. However. he's asking for quicksort and wants us to implement it all in one day and it's kind of ridiculous to expect us to learn the concept, the syntax and then implement it after a day. It's why I'm asking you guys for help :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have edited the question to be more clear. Also, it seems I can choose any variable to sort from the struct. Any suggestions? I'm considering sorting float hrs, could you guys help point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: @Dan In any case in order to sort something, you need this something to be stored somewhere. So you need to put your data inside an array. The sorted data should be an array as well, and since qsort is not an in-place algorithm, it should be another array. From here just go to your algorithms textbook or Google, and find the sorting algorithm. And implement it.

Comment: Time to divide and conquer.  Break code into `Read_Data(), Sort_Data(), Calculate(), Print_Report()`, etc.

Comment: quicksort is in-place but not stable, mergesort is stable and guaranteed O(n log n) but not in-place.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so lets say I wanted to sort the hours from variable hrs. Would I create something like float hoursArray [10]; (10 float arrays)? and then input that into the quciksort and the algorithm takes care of the rest?

Comment: @chux unfortunately I don't have enough time to do that right now (I'm still a newbie) but I will take the time to do that later when I'm done with the assignment and hopefully pick up a few things along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

1. You are only reading one EmployeeRecord and then it gets overwritten, if you want to sort them you have to save them all. You could work with `realloc` to dynamically change the size of the reserved space or keep it simple:

   ```
   EmployeeRecord employees[100]; // will fail if more than 100 employees are added
   ...
   // after em is complete:
   employees[counter++] = em; // remove the other counter++
   ```
2. Sorting taken from wikibooks.org and replaced the pointers by normal int, working with the index instead of pointer math (easier to understand) and added compare function which you will have to fill:

   ```
   void swap(int a, int b)
   {
       EmployeeRecord tmp = employees[a];
       employees[a] = employees[b];
       employees[b] = tmp;
   }

   int compare(int a, int b)
   {
       // return -1 if employees[a] comes before employees[b]
       // return  1 if employees[a] comes after employees[b]
       // return  0 "if they have the same order"
       //           (stable algorithms e.g. mergesort won't change the order of those)
   }

   void quicksort(int begin, int end)
   {
       int ptr;
       int split;
       if (end - begin <= 1)
           return;
       ptr = begin;
       split = begin + 1;
       while (++ptr <= end) {
           if (compare(ptr, split) > 0) { // sorts ascending
               swap(ptr, split);
               ++split;
           }
       }
       swap(begin, split - 1);
       quicksort(begin, split - 1);
       quicksort(split, end);
   }
   ```
3. Sort and create the report after the user decided to not continue any more.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the break down! It's exactly what I needed. I have a question regarding the counter though. The variable is still separate from the struct, right? So I could still divide the "total" variables by counter and get the average.

Comment: Yes, your totals and the counter is separate, those are not per employee but for all employees together. thanks for accepting.